# Auto Sum Input Value of Add Number Button Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to update the Input field with a button and auto display of all Input fields above. If the button is pressed, the input will automatically add a number and if there is an addition, the total input must also be added automatically.

```js
function eoscounting() {
  var Eos = parseInt(document.getElementById('eos_count').value, 10);
  Eos = isNaN(Eos) ? 0 : Eos;
  Eos++;
  document.getElementById('eos_count').value = Eos;
}

function basocounting() {
  var Baso = parseInt(document.getElementById('baso_count').value, 10);
  Baso = isNaN(Baso) ? 0 : Baso;
  Baso++;
  document.getElementById('baso_count').value = Baso;
}

function stabcounting() {
  var Stab = parseInt(document.getElementById('stab_count').value, 10);
  Stab = isNaN(Stab) ? 0 : Stab;
  Stab++;
  document.getElementById('stab_count').value = Stab;
}

function segcounting() {
  var Seg = parseInt(document.getElementById('seg_count').value, 10);
  Seg = isNaN(Seg) ? 0 : Seg;
  Seg++;
  document.getElementById('seg_count').value = Seg;
}

function monocounting() {
  var Mono = parseInt(document.getElementById('mono_count').value, 10);
  Mono = isNaN(Mono) ? 0 : Mono;
  Mono++;
  document.getElementById('mono_count').value = Mono;
}

function limcounting() {
  var Lim = parseInt(document.getElementById('lim_count').value, 10);
  Lim = isNaN(Lim) ? 0 : Lim;
  Lim++;
  document.getElementById('lim_count').value = Lim;
}

function findTotal() {
  const fees = document.querySelectorAll(".fee");
  const total = document.querySelector("#total");
  let sum = 0;

  fees.forEach(fee => {
    if (fee.valueAsNumber) {
      sum += fee.valueAsNumber;
    }
  });
  total.value = sum;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="eos_count" class="fee" name="qty" onchange="findTotal()" />
<input type="number" id="baso_count" class="fee" name="qty" onchange="findTotal()" />
<input type="number" id="stab_count" class="fee" name="qty" onchange="findTotal()" />
<input type="number" id="seg_count" class="fee" name="qty" onchange="findTotal()" />
<input type="number" id="mono_count" class="fee" name="qty" onchange="findTotal()" />
<input type="number" id="lim_count" class="fee" name="qty" onchange="findTotal()" />

<br /><br />
<input type="number" name="total" id="total" />
<br /><br />

<button class="input" value="myvalue" onclick="eoscounting()">Eosinofil</button>
<button class="input" value="myvalue" onclick="basocounting()">Basofil</button>
<button class="input" value="myvalue" onclick="stabcounting()">Netrofil Batang</button>
<button class="input" value="myvalue" onclick="segcounting()">Netrofil Segmen</button>
<button class="input" value="myvalue" onclick="monocounting()">Monosit</button>
<button class="input" value="myvalue" onclick="limcounting()">Limfosit</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Call `findTotal()` at the end of all the `xxxcounting()` functions.

Comment: since all counting functions are the same besides the name of the field they check, you should use only one function that takes the name of the field as argument: `function counting(what) { var val = parseInt(document.getElementById(what).value, 10); val = isNaN(val) ? 0 : val; val++; document.getElementById(what).value = val; }`. I just copied your function and hope that I didnt introduce a typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The on change event isn't being fired by your javascript because of the reason below.

> **change**
> The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its
> value has been modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for
> INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA. element.

You would need to manually trigger the onChange event, however I'm not completely sure how to do that. A quick solution would be to call the `findTotal()` function inside each of your counting functions.

```js
function eoscounting() {
  var Eos = parseInt(document.getElementById('eos_count').value, 10);
  Eos = isNaN(Eos) ? 0 : Eos;
  Eos++;
  document.getElementById('eos_count').value = Eos;
  findTotal();
}

function basocounting() {
  var Baso = parseInt(document.getElementById('baso_count').value, 10);
  Baso = isNaN(Baso) ? 0 : Baso;
  Baso++;
  document.getElementById('baso_count').value = Baso;
  findTotal();
}

function stabcounting() {
  var Stab = parseInt(document.getElementById('stab_count').value, 10);
  Stab = isNaN(Stab) ? 0 : Stab;
  Stab++;
  document.getElementById('stab_count').value = Stab;
  findTotal();
}

function segcounting() {
  var Seg = parseInt(document.getElementById('seg_count').value, 10);
  Seg = isNaN(Seg) ? 0 : Seg;
  Seg++;
  document.getElementById('seg_count').value = Seg;
  findTotal();
}

function monocounting() {
  var Mono = parseInt(document.getElementById('mono_count').value, 10);
  Mono = isNaN(Mono) ? 0 : Mono;
  Mono++;
  document.getElementById('mono_count').value = Mono;
  findTotal();
}

function limcounting() {
  var Lim = parseInt(document.getElementById('lim_count').value, 10);
  Lim = isNaN(Lim) ? 0 : Lim;
  Lim++;
  document.getElementById('lim_count').value = Lim;
  findTotal();
}

function findTotal() {
  const fees = document.querySelectorAll(".fee");
  const total = document.querySelector("#total");
  let sum = 0;

  fees.forEach(fee => {
    if (fee.valueAsNumber) {
      sum += fee.valueAsNumber;
    }
  });
  total.value = sum;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="eos_count" class="fee" name="qty" />
<input type="number" id="baso_count" class="fee" name="qty" />
<input type="number" id="stab_count" class="fee" name="qty" />
<input type="number" id="seg_count" class="fee" name="qty" />
<input type="number" id="mono_count" class="fee" name="qty" />
<input type="number" id="lim_count" class="fee" name="qty" />

<br /><br />
<input type="number" name="total" id="total" />
<br /><br />

<button class="input" value="myvalue" onclick="eoscounting()">Eosinofil</button>
<button class="input" value="myvalue" onclick="basocounting()">Basofil</button>
<button class="input" value="myvalue" onclick="stabcounting()">Netrofil Batang</button>
<button class="input" value="myvalue" onclick="segcounting()">Netrofil Segmen</button>
<button class="input" value="myvalue" onclick="monocounting()">Monosit</button>
<button class="input" value="myvalue" onclick="limcounting()">Limfosit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, because I'm still in the learning stage.